# Guacamole fails to connect to xRDP server

Tags: rdp, guacamole, xrdp

I have a xrdp server running and would like to connect to it using Guacamole. However, each time I try to make any RDP connection it always fails with "You Have Been Disconnected." I know it is a fault with guacamole because I can log into xRDP using Remmina RDP client using the same credentials. 
Here are my Logs:

/var/run/syslog :

```
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[1291]: Creating new client for protocol "rdp"
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[1291]: Connection ID is "$0c72bf59-0ff9-448d-a5a2-dc3229157122"
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[5737]: Security mode: ANY
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[5737]: Resize method: none
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[5737]: User "@cce2ec3d-03c5-4387-be88-054a00927f56" joined connection "$0c72bf59-0ff9-448d-a5a2-dc3229157122" (1 users now present)
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[5737]: Loading keymap "base"
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[5737]: Loading keymap "en-us-qwerty"
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 4736.455320] guacd[5749]: segfault at 8000000000 ip 0000008000000000 sp 00007f3bc9f8bc98 error 14
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 4736.455323] traps: guacd[5750] general protection ip:7f3bcb074c69 sp:7f3bc978ac98 error:0
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 4736.455323] 
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 4736.455325]  in libguac.so.5.0.0[7f3bcb070000+d000]
Jul 26 10:02:36 ubuntu guacd[1291]: Connection "$0c72bf59-0ff9-448d-a5a2-dc3229157122" removed.
```

/var/log/tomcat8/Catalina.out :

```
10:02:33.079 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  o.a.g.r.auth.AuthenticationService - Authentication attempt from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 for user "-------" failed.
10:02:33.943 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] WARN  o.a.g.r.auth.AuthenticationService - Authentication attempt from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 for user "jonathan" failed.
10:02:36.100 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.a.g.r.auth.AuthenticationService - User "guacadmin" successfully authenticated from 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1.
10:02:36.241 [http-nio-8080-exec-10] INFO  o.a.g.tunnel.TunnelRequestService - User "guacadmin" connected to connection "3".
10:02:38.179 [Thread-7] INFO  o.a.g.tunnel.TunnelRequestService - User "guacadmin" disconnected from connection "3". Duration: 1937 milliseconds
```

Connection settings:

- security mode: any
- port: 3389

I am on ubuntu server 16.04. Any possible solutions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Try:
>
> 1. Removing the `[path to libfreerdp*.so]/freerdp/guac*.so` files that were copied, assuming this is the case.
> 2. Create symbolic links within `[path to libfreerdp*.so]/freerdp/` to `/usr/local/lib/freerdp/guac*.so`, so you do not need to worry about
>      this going forward.

Source: [RDP stopped working v0.9.9 - Apache Guacamole](https://sourceforge.net/p/guacamole/discussion/1110834/thread/1b380caa/?limit=25).